# Самовосстановление содержимого файла

Tags: wordpress

Бодрого всем кодинга.
Что за непонятность!!!
Я взял css-файл - удалил в нём весь код (т.е. он пустой)
по адресу: сайт/wp-content/themes/sunspot/style.css - так оно и есть.
Но сайт остался в старом дизайне(!!!) Я вообще понять ни чего не могу.
И увидел, что css сайта ссылается на:
сайт/wp-content/themes/sunspot/style.css?ver=3.7.1
Но ведь он пустой(!!!)
И как так волшебная запись в конце адресной строки "style.css**?ver=3.7.1**" восстанавливает старый, в нём всё есть, всё по старому(!)???
*(C WordPress познакомился всего час назад - и уже в шоке!)*

**А самое главное, где он лежит на ftp?**

---

дополнение:
http://fregatkrsk.ru/wp-content/themes/sunspot/style.css?ver=3.7.1
http://fregatkrsk.ru/wp-content/themes/sunspot/style.css
Как это может быть?

---

Поиски по всему сайту, на вхождение текста **?ver=3.7.1** во всех файлах сайта ни к чему не привёл.
Такого словосочетания просто нет(!!!)
Это полтергейст? Откуда это? Как это? Что это?
Мне кажется это проделки движка WordPress - так как вижу это **"ЧУДО"** впервые, так же как и ковыряюсь с WordPress впервые

Answer (score 1):

куда ссылка там и должен лежать /wp-content/themes/sunspot/.

а насчёт ваших чудес, может чего напутали по новизне? например файл с удалённым контентом не сохранили?

Comment: @http://hashcode.ru/users/16487/bl79
Уговорили:  
см: http://fregatkrsk.ru/wp-content/themes/sunspot/style.css?ver=3.7.1  
http://fregatkrsk.ru/wp-content/themes/sunspot/style.css
Как это может быть?

Comment: Где-то он в кэше. Проверьте, что у вас не стоит плагина кэширования, если есть - удалите его кэш и выключите плагин на время вёрстки.

Гугл выдаёт что на этом же сайте подобный вопрос уже задавался. http://hashcode.ru/questions/211481/css-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-wordpress

Покажите ваш файл .htaccess.

Кстати, у вас нет ситуации, что переносили хостинг. Но в .htaccess или где-то в php прописан путь конкретно к этому файлу на старом хостинге?

Comment: @bl79
Вот он весь:
``
# BEGIN WordPress
# END WordPress
``
Про перенос хостинга вроде не переносился, мне его вот недавно дали.
Но тогда бы пути вели куда-то в другое место или нет?  
Или вы имеете ввижу там переписаны DNS-сервера на хостере и файлы берутся со старого хоста, в виде кэша?  
Скорее всего что-то с кэшированием в самом WordPress'е  
Так как в Drupal похожая ситуация с картинками, то там в администрировании в конфигурации есть - "Очистить кэш".  
А в WordPress - есть что-то подобное?  
-----------  
Плагины гляну.

Comment: Как мне кажется, варианта с кэшированием тут может быть только 3: 

1. Плагинами WP. Если установка новая, этих плагинов нет. По умолчанию сам WP не кэширует.

2. Включено в .htaccess. Но вот вы давали ссылки, подтверждают ситуацию, я раньше ваш сайт не видел в кэше у меня быть не могло. (Хотя если я нажал их одну за другой - может и кшировались?) Всеровно у вас .htaccess пустой, тоже отпадает.

3. Хостингом. Это надо у них узнавать что за дела. Возьмите бесплатный хостинг на hostinger.ru, поставьте по этой инструкции и никаких проблем: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r--xYFs8Tqk